# How to convert an already open file to string?

Tags: python, csv

Given an open file, return the contents as a string.( This assumes the autotester test the function with a random file so the variable should be open to multiple files of the same type)

```
def read_file(myfile):
'''(file) -> str
Read the open file and return as a string.'''
```

Comment: can you expand on the second part? do you mean arbitrary number of arguments, or a list?

Answer (score 1):

```
def read_file(myfile):
    return myfile.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
content = myfile.read()
```

Or to read it line by line and put it in a list:

```
content_list = myfile.readlines()
```

You can then use:

```
content_list = [x.strip() for x in content_list]
```

to remove \n characters.

Comment: `rstrip()` would be best suited, then to avoid removing leading spaces for instance (imagine reading a python program like this...)

Comment: Yes of course for parsing a python code you need rstrip(). But it depends on what you want to do with content. Thanks for your point :)

Answer (score 0):

After opening the file (I recommend using the `with` statement, e.g `with open(filename.txt, "r") as file`, use `fileString = file.read()` and `fileString` will be the contents

Answer (score 0):

To deal with larger files, it's a good idea to read in chunks of fixed size. If you try to open an image, for example, and don't use buffered reading, you'll get a `MemoryError`.

```
def read_file(filename):
    BUFFER_SIZE = 65536
    contents = []
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        while True:
            chunk = filename.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not chunk:
                break
            contents.append(chunk)
    return "".join(contents)
```